# php redis extension: version changes of function name about cases?

Tags: php, redis, case, version

I wonder that in which **versions**(php redis extension), cases of function name have changed ? like this:

```
$redis = new Redis();
$redis -> smembers($key);
// or
$redis -> sMembers($key);
```

Your answer will be appreciated. THX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The branch release 1.1 of phpredis had the syntax of `$redis->smembers($key);`

However the current develop phpredis has the new syntax of `$redis->sMembers($key);`

I am not sure if that's what you were looking for, however I recommend adjusting all old code to the new syntax for future support.

Comment: THX, a links refered to the description will be appreciated.